# Lookup last non blank cell associated with a value

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a table with two columns, `ID` and `Value`. Each `Value` is associated with an `ID`. However, some `Values` are blank.

**My table**

```
ID  Value
A2  102
A3  108
A4  
A2  148
A3  91
A5  13
A3  Dog
A4  119
A5  58
A3  
A4  Cat
A6
```

I want to look up the last non blank `Value` for each `ID`. I need this to work for all data types (numbers, strings, dates, etc). Also, some `IDs` may have no values at all. The formula should return "" for these.

**Desired results below**

```
ID  Last Value
A2    148
A3    Dog
A4    Cat
A5    58
A6
```

**What I've tried**

`=LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,IF(A2:A12=D2,IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B12),B2:B12)))` This works but only for numbers.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$12=D2),$B$2:$B$12)` Returns `0`, which is the blank for `A3`.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B12))),B2:B12)` Returns `92`, which is simply the last value.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$12=D2),(NOT(ISBLANK($B$2:$B$12))))` Returns `FALSE` is there is a blank and `TRUE` is there are no blanks.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$12=D2),NOT(ISBLANK($B$2:$B$12)),$B$2:$B$12)` but the syntax is incorrect (too many arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (as an array formula)

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention a case where an `ID` may not have any `Value` associated with it. Simply wrapping your formula in an `IF` and saying `IF(formula)="column_header", ""` (or `0` for numbers) did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: ...I forgot to make the range row references for Cols A and B absolute, so you also need that added.